Can calling sync inside concurrent queue cause a deadlock?
I know that calling sync inside a serial queue will cause a deadlock, e.g.
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")
serialQueue.async {
    serialQueue.sync {
        // deadlock
    }
}

But what if I write something like this:
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
concurrentQueue.async {
    concurrentQueue.sync {
        // deadlock?
    }
}

Yeah in general there won't be any deadlocks. Because our synchronous task will simply run on a different thread.
But can it happen that from the thread pool for a synchronous task the same thread on which the asynchronous task was assigned will be returned? If so, it could cause that thread get stuck and we would have a deadlock

You asked:

But can it happen that from the thread pool for a synchronous task the same thread on which the asynchronous task was assigned will be returned? If so, it could cause that thread get stuck and we would have a deadlock.

No, it will not deadlock for that reason.
That having been said, concurrent queues are susceptible to deadlocks for a multitude of other reasons: It can deadlock in thread explosion scenarios (as the worker thread pool is limited to 64 threads) and/or misuse of locks, barriers, wait on semaphore/group, target queues, etc. But it will not deadlock simply because it tried to use the “the same thread.”
Needless to say, this practice of dispatching synchronously to itself is best avoided, regardless.
